# App post notification to user. How do I get an access token for app?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the new version 2, sdk 4.0 php. I am trying to send a notification to a user with my app. I just realised the access token that I get via login (user access token) is different to the access token for my app. I have searched online before posting it on here, but most is for the old sdk and cannot get the right syntax to work with mine.

My code:

```
$notification = (new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'POST',
'/'.$id[0].'/notifications',
array (
    'href' => "http://localhost/app/index.php",
    'template' => 'You have been tagged, please set privacy preference',
 )

))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

And my error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php:134 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\privacy.php(121): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php on line 134

Can someone help me with getting the app access token?

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work: 'access_token' =>  'http://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token={id}|{secret}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the app access_token as follows:

```
$appSession = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
```

Then you can do:

```
$notification = (new FacebookRequest(
$appSession,
'POST',
'/'.$id[0].'/notifications',
array (
    'href' => "http://localhost/app/index.php",
    'template' => 'You have been tagged, please set privacy preference',
 )

))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: Thank you :) I am getting the error that the Object isn't found. The URL doesn't load: The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. 

The notification works now. Thank you! Do you know why the URL isn't working? :S I have tried the URL for localhost/canvas url but I still get the error..

Comment: Oh it works now! I changed "http://localhost/app/index.php" to just "index.php" and it works. Thank you so much though.